# Force Typescript to recognize __moduleName

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs

I'm trying to set up a build environment for Angular2 and SystemJs, such that I can import components from external libraries, which are defined like so:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: __moduleName,
  selector: 'foo-selector',
  templateUrl: 'foo.component.html'
})
```

I know for sure that this is what I want to use, because it works when I run it. But Typescript compilation fails because it can't recognize `moduleName`. How can I tell Typescript to recognize this, or at least, not to complain about it?

This is with Typescript version 2.1.0-dev.20160915 and `module` is set to `system` in `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add this line to your `typings/index.d.ts` file:

```
declare var __moduleName: string;
```

Comment: I have the same problem... but in my case, there is no compilation error.. But in browser i'm getting, 'localhost/:23 Error: (SystemJS) __moduleName is not defined' ... is there any solution?

Comment: What is your tsconfig.json looks like? Specifically `compilerOptions.module` section

Comment: Yeah.. Like the this , 
 "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "amd",
        "moduleResolution": "node"}

Comment: `_moduleName` is only for `"module": "system"`

Comment: For amd, is there anything like module.id or __ModuleName?

Comment: @Guna https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/module-formats.md#amd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123954/discussion-between-guna-and-yurzui).